# Wordpress - changing title tag within shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Seem to be having some difficulty with this.

I've got some shortcodes that I add.

```
add_shortcode("do_something", array($this, "my_function"));
```

so I'd place [do_something] in a wordpress post and it'd run my function. great. what I want.

my_function in this instance goes and gets some dynamic content to be shown on the page (think a list of products for example). This also all works fine. Whilst inside this function I also build up a string that I want to be in the  of my page.

I can't seem to get this to work from within 'my_function'. It works if I place it outside the function but then I don't have the content I need to dynamically set the title tag.

The code I'm using to set the header is the following:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'some_callback', 10 );
```

and the some_callback function:

```
    function some_callback($data){$title_tag = "test 123";  return $title_tag;}
```

As mentioned if I stick this in the same place I do the add_shortcode for example it works, if I put it inside 'my_function' it doesn't.

I assume this is something to do with order of operations but I can't think of a way around it.

cheers!

Comment: Nah. Thanks though.

Comment: nope. I did search before posting..

Comment: Is the objective to set the title with a shortcode in the post content? WordPress shortcodes are not designed to do this but I think it can be done with a some clever custom code. If this is your objective let me know and I will try and implement it. It will be a bit of work and I will do it only if this what you want.

Comment: I think this really a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665247/how-to-modify-page-title-in-shortcode and I have updated that question with my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665247/how-to-modify-page-title-in-shortcode/53600417#53600417.

Comment: I think this is what I'm after. Cheers magenta

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to modify the document title via hooks after the title has already been generated, but you could do it via javascript by appending something like this to your shortcode output:

```
$generatedTitle = "Your generated title";
echo "<script>document.title = '" . $generatedTitle . "';</script>";
```

If you're worried about how search engines will cope, Google and other reputable search engines will run the JS while crawling your site and show the changed title in the search results.

Comment: That could be a solution. I'm going to run into the same issue with meta tags. Seems a bit silly it can't be changed pre-render. Can I prevent the title being generated until my hook? Would that be a solution?

Comment: The title tag has to be in the head section of the HTML, so no, you can't do that. You'd probably be better off defining a new page template for your theme for any pages you want to have a dynamic title tag for: [https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Comment: Although, WordPress was not designed to do this with shortcodes it can be done with some clever code. See my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665247/how-to-modify-page-title-in-shortcode/53600417#53600417

Comment: Nice solution - however that solution suits this question better, as this one is for the document title, the other question is about the page title.